Vlookup the equivalent value if it matches or fits inside a range

How to VLOOKUP the equivalent value if it matches or fits inside a range. Is there a way to get this using vlookup?
Normal VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH formulas are not working.
The Excel file I currently working on is already large and linked on the different sheets and tabs, so I can no longer adjust/create another column.

If you are using Excel, don't include google-sheet tags please. Also, include a desired output,  preferably insert data-samples using Markdown Tables. Did you do any research?

Can data outside the Ratings exist?  (e.g. 7.38%, which is between 6.88% — maximum for Rating 99 — and 7.88% — minimum for Rating 95)

It needs two checks with logical AND and disclose not in range results.
The formula:
=INDEX(Sheet8!A$2:A$5,MATCH(1,(A2>=Sheet8!B$2:B$5)*(A2<=Sheet8!C$2:C$5),0))
where Sheet8 is the table of ranges.


The required formula is very simple (refers ranges depicted below):
[B2]=XLOOKUP(A2:A18,E2:E5,D2:D5,"",-1)


Generaly, upper range limits (Range 2) are not required.
For earlier versions of Excel VLOOKUP works:
[B2 and fill down]=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$1:$F$5,3,TRUE)

You need to reorder columns in the reference table:

